# put https link in i18n translation file in react

Tags: reactjs, i18next, language-translation

I'm using i18n into translate my multi language react project.
I have a sentences that contain (:) character:

```
"e.g https://192.168.1.15 or https://example.com"
```

and I want to translate that to Persian like this:

```
"مثال: https://192.168.1.15 یا https://example.com"
```

I put that in  my translation file like this:

```
export default {
"e.g https://192.168.1.15 or https://example.com": "مثال: https://192.168.1.15 یا https://example.com",
}
```

but it doesn't work. I realized the ":" is the issue . What I see is this:

```
 "//192.168.1.15 or httpsfalse//example.com"
```

How can I Use (:) character in my translation in i18n?

Comment: It is not clear what the issue from what you have wrote, can you provide a small repo which reproduces the issue? or codesandbox, https://codesandbox.io/s/8187wm9yj8

Comment: the problem is using ":" character in translation. How can I translate the sentences that is contain a ":" character?

Comment: Can you use a custom key that doesn't use special characters? `e.g.` "exampleUrl": "مثال: https://192.168.1.15 یا https://example.com"`

Comment: thank you. yes, I've used the similar solution and posted it in the answer section. but I think it is not the perfect way to resolve the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this solution:

```
t("e.g.", {
  urlIP: "https://192.168.1.15",
  urlDomain: "https://example.com",
 })
```

and put this code in my translation file:

en.js:

```
"e.g.": "e.g. {{urlIP}} or {{urlDomain}}",
```

fa.js:

```
"e.g.": "مثال: {{urlIP}} یا {{urlDomain}}",
```

It's not the best solution and I think there is a better way to resolve this issue, but it works for now.

If you know better solution, I am glad to hear from you.

Answer (score 0):

":" has a special meaning when inside a translation key, it means what is the namespace which the key belongs to.

I had similar issue with one of mine translation keys, the solution was to ignore the namespace in that specific key.

```
t("Welcome to React :)", {nsSeparator: false})
// ---------------------------^ this will make the lib to ignore the ":"
```

For more info, you can read this [bug](https://github.com/i18next/i18next/issues/1456)

Comment: Unfortunately this solution doesn't work for me  :((

Comment: Which version of i18next do you use? it got fixed last week...

Comment: https://github.com/i18next/i18next/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#1956